# How to delete a row in a table with a primary key, without deleting the value of anothers table Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's assume:

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
ID_Client int primary key,
Name varchar(20));

CREATE TABLE Sale(
X int primary key,
ID_Client int REFERENCES Client(ID_Client));

INSERT INTO Client VALUES(123456, 'Sam');

INSERT INTO Sale VALUES(1, 123456);
```

How do I delete 'Sam' without deleting the Sale, and without losing It's FK value?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without losing It's FK value"? Are you trying to preserve `1` or `123456`?

Comment: Remove a foreign key constraint?

Comment: In your example, `delete 'Sam' without deleting the Sale, and without losing It's FK value` means that you need just update Sam's name

Comment: As @zerkms asked and many have written in the answer, I would second that. If you have to delete data but keep it in another table then there is no point to use FK in the first place. So, just drop the FK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key introduced by `ID_Client REFERENCES Client` as is forbids that `ID_Client` takes on values that are not contained in `Client`. Hence, you cannot delete the client record `Sam` without having first either deleted the `Sale`-record or having changed the respective sales record's `client_id` to point to something else.

If you want to save the sales records, you could write `ID_Client REFERENCES Client(ID_Client) ON DELETE SET NULL`, such that the DBMS will correct references to (deleted) master records in any slave record and set the slave record's `ID_Client`-value to `NULL`. Of course, you will loose the information that the ID of the (deleted) client record was `123456`, since this then were not a "valid" reference any more and must not occur therefore in the slave record.

If you want to keep the value `123456` as well, you'd have to drop the foreign key constraint. Note that you still can join client and sale; yet the DBMS does not ensure referential integrity for you. You have to check this then on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop the foreign key constraint `ALTER TABLE Sale DROP CONSTRAINT ...` and then you could delete the row... But there's a consistency problem because you can have sale that refers to unknown client.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can not have a foreign key reference and NOT have the key in the REFERENCED table.
   you can DROP the FK reference and delete the row with 'Sam'.
2. if you want to keep the constraints and bascially NOT have 'Sam', insert NULL in place of 'Sam'.